# Scrolling text inside a textbox

Tags: wpf, textbox

I have a WPF app with a textbox that I'm sending text to throughout the run cycle of the app.
As I'm feedign data to the text box to give updates from the app I want the text inside the textbox to scroll down with the data. Right now the scroll bar stays at the top of the textbox and I have to scroll down to see what has been inserted into the control. How do i eneable it so I don't have to scroll down to see the text?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use a ListBox instead of a TextBox, and then Bind it to an ObservableCollection on your ViewModel.

```
public ObservableCollection<string> MyUpdates {get; set;}
```

Then, whenever you update a message (from your Model), you can just add it to the head of the collection:

```
MyUpdates.Insert(0, your_message_here);
```

Your view is automatically refreshed and your new messages are on top.

(You can probably play with different containers for that, depending on what you want, and if you want a scrolbar or not. Have a look at [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/659066/ListBox-and-Panels-in-WPF) for examples)

Answer (score 1):

There is a method on `TextBox` just for this: [`TextBox.ScrollToEnd()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.textboxbase.scrolltoend.aspx).

Call that method whenever text is added to the `TextBox`.